# What is the correct syntax to accomplish my task?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am learning python through an online course. One of the tasks is to create a function that asks for the users' age. Put the function in a `.py` file, then run it from the command line.
Everything seems to work fine. The file is created, I call the file and receive the expected result, but I also get a syntax error and I can't figure out why. Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?!

I know if I change it from a `.py` to `.txt` it runs with no errors, but the request is for a `.py` and I can't figure out the problem.

I am running Python version 3.8.5.

Here is my code:

```
def your_age(year):
    return f"You are {year} years old!"

your_age(46)

answer = your_age(46)

file_name = input("Enter a file name: ")

file_name = f"{file_name}.py"

with open(file_name, "w") as f:
    f.write(answer)
    f.close
```

[image: Screenshot of my syntax error]

---

***Update***

Thank you everyone for your help.

I realized I was focusing too much on the error and not the actual task.

Correct, I was to put the function itself into a `.py` file and then call the file in order to get the required result. Making the age a constant was just for the basis of practice. I have re-written my code and actually saved it to a `.py` file.

I have removed the constant age and added the question 'How old are you?

Here is the updated code:

```
year = ()

def your_age(year):
    year = input("How old are you? ")
    return f"You are {year} years old!"

age = your_age(year)

print(age)
```

Comment: I'm 99.99% sure the question telling you to create a py file with the function, not actually write the result **to a python file**

Comment: The task says to put the *function* in a `.py` file, it doesn't say to put the output there.

Comment: Please post the exact text of the assignment. It seems like you misunderstood it.

Comment: I'm sure that when they said "Put the function in a .py file, then run it from the command line" the mean that you need toy write the program in a `.py` file that ask your age and then run that program. Not that you have to write a program that writes a program that ask your age and then run the program your program created.

Comment: Aren't you supposed to ask for the user's age? You are asking for a filename and using a constant age... Also there is no need for `file.close()` when using a `with` statement

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to execute a file with Python that has no valid Python code. The file `test1.py` contains:

```py
You are 46 years old!
```

...which is not valid Python.
If you want to execute this file with Python, you have to make sure that it has valid syntax.

A possible solution to your problem would be editing your `your_age` function to return a valid Python statement, like this:

```py
def your_age(year):
    return f"print('You are {year} years old!')"
```

With this, your `test1.py` file would contain:

```py
print('You are 46 years old!')
```

...which is valid Python code!

Upon calling `python test1.py`, `You are 46 years old!` will be printed to the console.

Comment: That's not correct, either. You're missing quotes around the string in the output file.

Comment: It's very unlikely that an exercise for a beginner would have this as the requirement.

Comment: [edited] I agree. However, the question states "but the request is for a .py". This was the only way that the statement would be true... I still think it's weird though.

Comment: He misunderstood. The request was for the function to be in a .py, not the output.

Comment: The line he misunderstood was `Put the function in a .py file`

Comment: oh my! so in a way, OP went way beyond the original task from the course hahaha